# I can't access apache on vagrant windows

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I have built a vagrant box using puphet. When I do vagrant up the box is up and running fine. I turned on apache2 webserver within the box as well. Now from outside the box can't access the apache server by type in 192.168.56.101 (the box's address). I know the issue is related to address binding but I don't know exactly how to do it. below is my puphet config.yaml file:

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        hostname: local.puphpet
        memory: '512'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.101
            forwarded_port:
                vflnp_31e44uhwa2cu:
                    host: '7116'
                    guest: '22'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_fs3ofbm89qyh:
                source: ./
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - vim
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_ssb4bugd70ex:
            server_name: box.dev
            www_root: /var/www/dev
            listen_port: '80'
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_port: '443'
            locations:
                nxvl_ywa6hbmvw3ow:
                    location: /var/www/dev
                    autoindex: off
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - index.php
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: ''
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                nxvl_97g611caj500:
                    location: '~ \.php$'
                    autoindex: off
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - index.php
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename'
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_osa2smyuqr4y:
            servername: box.dev
            docroot: /var/www/dev
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            directories:
                avd_xzvy3s5w3fa0:
                    path: /var/www/dev
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_pkcnczff12f4:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '56'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
            - gd
            - curl
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools: {  }
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.17.1
drush:
    install: '1'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        rv_ozgubxwi5uc5:
            default: '1'
            version: 1.9.3
            gems:
                - compass
                - sass
                - susy
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    npm_packages: {  }
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings: {  }
    server_ini: {  }
    php_ini: {  }
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.6'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mysqlnu_7nkrzrugn90t:
            name: admin
            password: admin
    databases:
        mysqlnd_mxo03ad3grcv:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_cyb893kjef9n:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.3'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
    adminer: 0
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mailcatcher:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: headers
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 1.4.1
        java_install: true
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

And here is the error that I get when I type in the address into the browser:

> ERROR
>
> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> While trying to retrieve the URL: http://192.168.56.101:443/
>
> The following error was encountered:
>
> Connection to 192.168.56.101 Failed The system returned:
>
> ```
> (10060) WSAETIMEDOUT, Connection timed out. The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.
> ```
>
> Your cache administrator is webmaster.  Generated Mon, 27 Apr 2015
>   11:21:55 GMT by ISMGNT05 (squid/2.7.STABLE4)

Comment: Do you try https or localhost?

Comment: yes, I already did. I ran the box on Mac and use 192.168.56.101 it is working fine as well. But when move to windows i counter this problem

Comment: Whats say with https://192.168.56.101:443 and https://localhost:443 ?

Comment: it say the same things i have tried following combination  192.168.56.101:443  192.168.56.101  192.168.56.101:7116 and localhost for the same port. The weird things is still can ssh into the box through 192.168.56.101. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> I ran the box on Mac and use 192.168.56.101
>
> The weird things is still can ssh into the box through 192.168.56.101

Sounds like port 80 on your Windows machine is being used up! Do you have Skype installed on Windows and not on OSX (or any other device using port 80)?

Use this link to see what ports are being used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199/446766 and disable the program using 80.

Comment: hi thank i checked port 80 it is using by VBoxHeadless.exe and the firewall status is "Allowed, not restricted". I found out that if enter 127.0.0.1:7116 on browser it is showing me "Open SSh-2.0 Protocol Mismatch". I also see that when VBox boot up the ports parameter in the conf.yaml file which are 7116 and 22 are foward to port 22.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing
 network:

> ```
>         private_network: 192.168.56.101
>         forwarded_port:
>             vflnp_31e44uhwa2cu:
>                 host: '7116'
>                 guest: '22'
> ```

to

> ```
>                 host: '80'
>                 guest: '80'
> ```

in config.yaml files and the ip address to access the box is 127.0.0.1